# String is bound multiple times in Dagger

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I've a problem in injecting Strings in dagger

This is my implementation

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class,
        ViewModelModule::class,
        NetModule::class,
        AppModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    fun inject(theDApplication: TFTScreenApplication)

    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        @Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY)
        fun apiUrl(apiUrl: String): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        @Named(Constants.SOCKET_URL_KEY)
        fun socketUrl(socketUrl: String): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Then in Net Module

```
@Module
abstract class NetModule {

    @Binds
    @Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY)
    abstract fun provideApiUrl(apiUrl: String): String

    @Binds
    @Named(Constants.SOCKET_URL_KEY)
    abstract fun provideSocketUrl(socketUrl: String): String

    @Module
    companion object {

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
            return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesGson(): Gson {
            val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
            gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            return gsonBuilder.create()
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesRetrofit(
            @Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY) apiUrl: String, gson: Gson
        ): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                .build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesBackOffStrategy(): BackoffStrategy {
            return ExponentialWithJitterBackoffStrategy(5000, 5000)
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesLifeCycle(application: Application): Lifecycle {
            return AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(application)
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesScarlet(
            @Named(Constants.SOCKET_URL_KEY) socketUrl: String, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
            backoffStrategy: BackoffStrategy,
            lifecycle: Lifecycle
        ): Scarlet {
            return Scarlet.Builder()
                .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory(socketUrl))
                .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
                .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
                .backoffStrategy(backoffStrategy)
                .lifecycle(lifecycle)
                .build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesCoinSocket(scarlet: Scarlet): SocketService {
            return scarlet.create(SocketService::class.java)
        }

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        @JvmStatic
        fun providesPISAPIs(retrofit: Retrofit): PISAPIs {
            return retrofit.create(PISAPIs::class.java)
        }
    }
```

The error is

> error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] java.lang.String is bound multiple
>   times: public abstract interface AppComponent extends
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
>                   ^
>         @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Named("API_URL") @BindsInstance
>   com.example.tftscreen.common.di.component.AppComponent.Builder
>   com.example.tftscreen.common.di.component.AppComponent.Builder.apiUrl(String)
>         @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Named("SOCKET_URL") @BindsInstance
>   com.example.tftscreen.common.di.component.AppComponent.Builder
>   com.example.tftscreen.common.di.component.AppComponent.Builder.socketUrl(String)
>         java.lang.String is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.NetModule.provideSocketUrl(socketUrl)
>         @javax.inject.Named("SOCKET_URL") java.lang.String is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.NetModule.providesScarlet(socketUrl,
>   …)
>         com.tinder.scarlet.Scarlet is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.NetModule.providesCoinSocket(scarlet)
>         com.example.tftscreen.pis.SocketService is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.pis.data.PISRemoteRepository(socketService, …)
>         com.example.tftscreen.pis.data.PISRemoteRepository is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.pis.PISViewModel(pisRemoteRepository)
>         com.example.tftscreen.pis.PISViewModel is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.ViewModelModule.bindPISViewModel(pisViewModel)
>         java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider>
>   is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.presentationLayer.ViewModelFactory(creators)
>         com.example.tftscreen.common.presentationLayer.ViewModelFactory is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.ViewModelModule.provideViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory)
>         androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
>             com.example.tftscreen.pis.PISActivity.viewModelFactory
>         com.example.tftscreen.pis.PISActivity is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.example.tftscreen.common.di.component.AppComponent →
>   com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.ActivityBuilder_BindMainActivity.PISActivitySubcomponent]
>   It is also requested at:
>         com.example.tftscreen.common.di.module.NetModule.provideApiUrl(apiUrl)

Comment: did you try removing your methods marked with `@Binds`?

Comment: I cannot because by doing the the Strings won't be provided
java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Comment: ok , but why not use the `@Provide` for those? I'm a little not clear on how you use the `@Binds` annotation . It usualy is used on providing interfaces where classes implement them.

Comment: because i use those as abstract methods and we cannot use provides with abstract methods and i use it inside app component because the app component is an interface

Comment: by using BindsInstance you wont need to have Provider methods in your module. Are you passing those 2 strings when you instantiate your dagger component?
Also, what happens if you annotate the parameters with the @Named(...) annotation instead of the methods?

Answer (score 3):

`@BindsInstance`, is most useful when you have dependencies that need to be introduced into the object graph at *runtime*.

`@Binds` is used when you need to bind an interface to an implementation *and* dagger can construct the concrete implementation for you (through an `@Inject` constructor)

It doesn't look like your `Constants.SOCKET_URL_KEY` & `Constants.API_URL_KEY` meet either of these criteria, so...

If it's true that these are available at compile time *and* you want dagger to provide these, then the easiest way to do that would be to add the following to your module:

```
@Provides
@JvmStatic
@Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY)
fun providesApiUrlKey(): String {
  return "YOUR_API_KEY"      
}
```

and remove:

```
@BindsInstance
@Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY)
fun apiUrl(apiUrl: String): Builder
```

In either situation (available at runtime or compile time), you'll need to remove this:

```
@Binds
@Named(Constants.API_URL_KEY)
abstract fun provideApiUrl(apiUrl: String): String

@Binds
@Named(Constants.SOCKET_URL_KEY)
abstract fun provideSocketUrl(socketUrl: String): String
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Named` annotation before your String to identify them.